# Remove codeartifact login form python in mac

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, macos, aws-codeartifact

I have connected to the codeartifact private lib on aws using some scripts after that even when i am trying to download some packages related to python on my mac it is saying python packages not present on the codeartifact python lib. I faced the similar issue for node but it got resolved by cleaning all the entries in the .npmrc file is there similar file for python?

I tried unsetting any export variables related to codeartifact but it did not worked. I am still getting below error whenever i am trying to get any public python packages.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for this apparently there is a similar file that for python that stores the login token that is generated when you make connection with codeartifact file can be found at this ~/.config/pip/pip.conf removing the token from here solved the issue for me